# Working with csv files that have delimiters

Tags: python

I have to read data from a csv file and I want to convert two columns by making use of one hot encoding.

The csv files data has one column with ';' in between the data (E.g. CITY;MONTH;SALES_AMOUNT). How do I load this in pandas dataframe in separate columns?

Desired result : E.g   `CITY  MONTH SALES_AMOUNT`

Instead of: `CITY;MONTH;SALES_AMOUNT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the delimiter parameter when reading the CSV file.

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', delimiter = ';')
```